# javascript flashcard

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can someone please tell me why the following extension does not work? I tried to replace the inline script with script src=" ..." /script and it still doesn't work. Is it better to list both javascripts in content scripts or remove them both?

POPUP.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body { width: 300px; }
  textarea { width: 250px; height: 100px;}
</style>
<script>
  function pasteSelection() {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getSelection"}, function (response) {
  var text = document.getElementById('text'); 
  text.innerHTML = response.data;
    });
  });
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="text"> </textarea>
<button onclick="pasteSelection(); ">Paste Selection</button>
</body>
</html>
```

selection.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.method == "getSelection")
  sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
else
  sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
 "name": "Selected Text",
 "version": "0.1",
 "description": "Selected Text",
 "browser_action": {
 "default_title": "Selected Text",
 "default_icon": "online.png",
 "default_popup": "popup.html" 
},
 "permissions": [
 "tabs",
 "chrome://favicon/",
 "http://*/*", 
 "https://*/*"
],
 "content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["http://*/*"],
"js": ["selection.js", "paste.js"]
"run_at": "document_start",
"all_frames": true
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any inline code and you are using several depreciated methods. Not moving all of the inline code to an external file is probably what is causing the problem, but it is not good to use depreciated methods anyway. Fixing it would make it look like this:

**Popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body { width: 300px; }
      textarea { width: 250px; height: 100px;}
    </style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="text"> </textarea>
    <button id="pasteButton">Paste Selection</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Popup.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
  var pasteButton = document.getElementById("pasteButton");
  pasteButton.onclick = function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true}, function(tab) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id,{method:"getSelection"},function(response){
        var text = document.getElementById('text'); 
        text.innerHTML = response.data;
      });
    });
  };
};
```

**selection.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.method == "getSelection")
    sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
  else
    sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
 "name": "Selected Text",
 "version": "0.1",
 "description": "Selected Text",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "browser_action": {
   "default_title": "Selected Text",
   "default_icon": "online.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html" 
 },
 "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "chrome://favicon/",
   "http://*/*", 
   "https://*/*"
 ],
 "content_scripts": [{
   "matches": ["http://*/*"],
   "js": ["selection.js", "paste.js"],
   "run_at": "document_start",
   "all_frames": true
 }]
}
```

Comment: I've replaced "paste.js" in manifest.json with "popup.js", and the script still doesn't work. What do I do?

Comment: @query no, `popup.js` is for the `poup.html` page. You don't need to replace anything, this code is working as is.